# Помогите исправить Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this в osStore 1.5.5

Tags: php, opencart, модули, opencart2.0

В чекауте, при переходе к подтверждению оплаты вылетает:
Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in X:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\catalog\controller\payment\rbs.php on line 252

line 252:

```
    private function get_template($template, $this->data) {
        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/' . $template . '.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/' . $template . '.tpl', $this->data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/' . $template . '.tpl', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

PS адаптировал модуль оплаты для osStore 2.1 под osStore 1.5.5

Answer (score 1):

До версии 2.0.Х Нужно использовать метод render()

```
 private function get_template($template) {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/' . $template . '.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/' . $template . '.tpl';
       
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/' . $template . '.tpl';
    }
    return $this->render();
}
```

Comment: $this->data используется при вызове, чтобы передать значение, а принимаем мы его уже как $data:
В таком случае вылетает:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Loader::view() in ... on line 256

Comment: 252: private function get_template($template, $data) { и 256: return $this->load->view('default/template/' . $template . '.tpl', $data);

Comment: Понял вашу проблему. Вы откатываете код к 1.5.5. обновил ответ

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.

Comment: Теперь после перехода к оплате: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in X:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\system\library\rbs.php on line 109
line 109:
private function gateway($method, $this->data) {

Comment: Полагаю, там то же самое. $this->data и заменяйте $this->load->view на render с указанием темплейта

Comment: line 109 private function gateway($method, $this->data) { Убрал ", $this->data" вылетели ошибки по другим файлам. Notice: Undefined index: cart_id in X:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\catalog\controller\payment\rbs.php on line 57Notice: Undefined index: cart_id in X:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\catalog\controller\payment\rbs.php on line 65
Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() in X:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\system\library\rbs_discount.php on line 244

Comment: Смотрите что где откуда берётся. Хз что добавить.. Откат он такой